# Excel 2010 column graph round percentage values to over than 100%

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a graph showing percentages with a Data Table alongside. Excel 2010 rounds the values so that columns can sum to more than 100%, but I want every column in the graph to total exactly 100%.

Furthermore, some values like 0.0001 show 0, and I'd like to display something like 0* in the table so it will be clear that this is a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Have you tried implementing banker's rounding?

Comment: See the comment I gave on Carl's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a separate column with this formula:

```
=IF(A1>100%,100%,IF(A1<=0.1%,"0*",A1))
```

(where `A1` is the cell where the actual percent result is posted on your worksheet). Your graph would have to reference this column’s results. This will indicate that anything above 100% will be noted as 100%, and anything above zero, but less than 0.1%, will show as 0*; but if it is really zero, it will show 0. You may have to format the original columns for percent with two decimal places.

Comment: I have no problem with the actual result in the columns. The problem is in the way they are presented in the graph's data table - it is only rounded there.

Answer (score 0):

Data tables in charts are rather inflexible, since you have almost no control over formatting, nor over what to include or exclude from the table. What I've always done is make a custom table in the cells adjacent to the chart with whatever values and formats I need.